# SQLCipher commercial version and FTS3

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search, sqlcipher, fts3

I'm already using `FTS3`, after adding sqlite amalgamation as static library end enabling `FTS3` (following this tutorial http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/16/sqlite-full-text-search-for-iphone-ipadyour-own-sqlite-for-iphone-and-ipad/).

The database the app is searching into contains copyrighted text, so I have decided to use SQLCypher commercial version and it includes `FTS3` already enabled, if I'm not mistaken.
I haved added SqlCipher static library following http://sqlcipher.net/support/ and then removed previously added sqlite static library, is this correct? should I keep only `libsqlcipher.a` in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for supporting SQLCipher by using iOS commercial edition! You are correct, you can simply have libsqlcipher.a linked with your project, it contains everything you need for all platforms.